# How to set default language in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I did changed my `language` setting in `config/web.php` to:

```
'language'=> 'lv-LV'
```

But when I open the page language set from `accept-language` header from browser.

How I can fix it?

Comment: check if the html-header in views/layouts/main.php outputs the language reference correctly

Comment: <html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>"> I have this in my layout.php

Answer (score 0):

Considering [this](https://github.com/samdark/yii2-cookbook/blob/master/book/i18n-selecting-application-language.md) article, check:

1. If there any other blocks/files set language: `Yii::$app->language =...`.
2. Check for preferred language: `Yii::$app->request->getPreferredLanguage...`.
3. Check your url manager config. Language might come with request.

Comment: Thx, I has one config in 'as beforeRequest', kill them and simple 'language'=> 'lv-LV' now works)